# How would I conditionally format the font color for an unsummarized field in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a numeric field in my data source that is unsummarized. There is no aggregation on this field.

- I would like to format this field to use a red font color whenever the field value is greater than or equal to 100.
- Otherwise, I would like the font color unaltered.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this in the Power BI Conditional Formatting dialogs.

If I try:

**Format By:** Field Value

**Apply To:** Values Only

I cannot select the field in the Based on field.  It is grayed out.

If I try:

**Format By:** Rules

**Based of Field:**

It immediately plugs a 'Count of ' aggregation qualifier on the field.  There is no way to turn off the summarization.

I simply want to use a red font color if a field value is greater than or equal to 100.  Is there any way to do this in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using your field as a dimension (e.g. row/column header or the x-axis on a chart), it's pretty much always going to be aggregated (summarized) inside the visual, even if it only has a single value. If you have a single value, then MAX, MIN, SUM, AVERAGE should all return the same value and you can use any of them as your summarization.

The automatic summarization of a field is called an "implicit measure". You generally have more control writing your own explicit measures. For times when I know that I only want a single value, I tend to write explicit measures like this

```
FieldValue = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Field] )
```

The advantage of this over MAX or SUM is that I get a blank when there are multiple values, alerting me that something has gone wrong.

Explicit measures like this will show up as options to use in the conditional formatting interface.

---

More information on implicit and explicit measures:

https://radacad.com/explicit-vs-implicit-dax-measures-in-power-bi

https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-explicit-vs-implicit-measures-in-power-bi-e35b578808ca

Comment: Thank you Alexis.  I have much to learn about Power BI.  I starting to think that I can produce the reports easier in SQL and C#.